# Unable to upgrade Datastax Opscenter agent from 6.0.3 to 6.0.5

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

I tried to upgrade Opscenter from 6.0.3 to 6.0.5.  Agent upgrade failed with the following exception.  It seemed to have trouble logging into the nodes.  I believe I put in the correct user id and private key.

```
2016-11-17 23:39:47,976 [opscenterd]  INFO: using ssh-private-key (async-thread-macro-12)
2016-11-17 23:39:47,979 [opscenterd]  INFO: Trying to establish ssh connection ssh-management-address="172.31\
.46.195" node-name="unmanaged-node-172.31.46.195" node-id="f8768526-59d9-43c6-99e0-3adaf34cc220" job-id="2898\
d02d-d2f6-4021-a17b-39a2eb930a74" (async-thread-macro-12)
2016-11-17 23:39:47,982 [opscenterd]  INFO: Trying to establish ssh connection ssh-management-address="172.31\
.28.101" node-name="unmanaged-node-172.31.28.101" node-id="241ea5a7-fb5c-457e-b58d-4acfb1eb562a" job-id="2898\
d02d-d2f6-4021-a17b-39a2eb930a74" (async-thread-macro-11)
2016-11-17 23:39:48,026 [opscenterd] ERROR: Unexpected error processing install_agent job 2898d02d-d2f6-4021-\
a17b-39a2eb930a74 on node name="unmanaged-node-172.31.55.196" ssh-management-address="172.31.55.196" node-id=\
"b830d52b-1707-4702-aaf3-950d4158fdf9" (async-thread-macro-10)
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: USERAUTH fail
        at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey.start(UserAuthPublicKey.java:119)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:463)
        at clj_ssh.ssh$fn__18053.invoke(ssh.clj:119)
        at clj_ssh.ssh.protocols$fn__18011$G__17978__18020.invoke(protocols.clj:4)
        at clj_ssh.ssh$connect.invoke(ssh.clj:404)
        at lcm.jobs.multinode.common$run_command$fn__18856$fn__18858.invoke(common.clj:735)
        at lcm.jobs.multinode.common$run_command$fn__18856.invoke(common.clj:731)
        at lcm.jobs.multinode.common$run_command.invoke(common.clj:713)
        at lcm.jobs.multinode.install_agent.InstallAgentJob.run(install_agent.clj:36)
        at lcm.jobs.multinode.common$run_job.invoke(common.clj:73)
        at lcm.jobs.multinode.common$process_run__18529$fn__18530.invoke(common.clj:91)
        at clojure.core.async$thread_call$fn__8945.invoke(async.clj:434)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: OpsCenter developer here, I can confirm that's an auth error... but there isn't enough information in this post to give any meaningful advice beyond attempt to log in manually to verify your credentials, and delete your ssh-credentials in LCM and create them again, being very careful to enter them correctly.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the reply.  LCM was not used to upgrade the agent.  When I brought up the new version of opscenter, it detected that the agents were outdated.  I clicked the link to upgrade and entered the user ID and pasted the private key there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually upgrading the OpsCenter agent on each node:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade datastax-agent`